# Perform a maven deploy-file with gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy, deployment, build.gradle

I need to deploy an external zip file to my private maven repository. This file will content my application version release, internally the archive will content the file structure of my application with jars, dlls, configs, exes...

How can I perform a maven deploy:deploy-file using gradle?

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
-DgroupId=acme 
-DartifactId=acme 
-Dversion=1.0 
-Dpackaging=jar 
-Dfile=C:\tmp\acme-1.0.jar 
-DrepositoryId=Nexus 
-Durl=http://myserver:8888/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
```

I'm trying this to publish an external zip file to my maven repository:

```
apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

publishing {
    def host = "myhost"
    def url = "http://$host/content/repositories/releases"
    def group = "package"
    def artifact = "name"
    def version = "0.0.1"
    def file = "c:/my.zip"

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            create('zip', MavenPublication) {
                groupId "$group"
                artifactId "$artifact"
                version "$version"
                artifact file("$file")
            }       
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'user'
                password 'pwd'
            }
            url "$url"
        }
    }
}

publish.dependsOn build
```

But when it execute, I get this exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'c:\xxxx\build.gradle' line: 18

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'XXXXX'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing(ExtensionContainer)
   > No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [0.0.1]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting case, not that obvious at the first sight. The problem is that the methods (`version`, `artifact`) in this block:

```
mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
  create('zip', MavenPublication) {
     groupId "$group"
     artifactId "$artifact"
     version "$version"
     artifact file("$file")
  }       
}
```

are named exactly the same as the variables that are defined few lines above in this block:

```
def host = "myhost"
def url = "http://$host/content/repositories/releases"
def group = "package"
def artifact = "name"
def version = "0.0.1"
def file = "c:/my.zip"
```

What happens here is that in *publication* block version is evaluated to *0.0.1* and then an argument with the same value is passed to it, it results in:

```
"0.0.1"("0.0.1")
```

It explains the error message:

> No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for
> argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl)

In fact the second argument will be `GString` not bare `String` and secondly there's no `call` method defined on `String` class in groovy which accepts an instance of a `String`.

I added *whatever* suffix to all problematic names:

```
apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

publishing {
    def host = "myhost"
    def urlWhataver = "http://$host/content/repositories/releases"
    def group = "package"
    def artifactWhatever = "name"
    def versionWhatever = "0.0.1"
    def path = "c:/my.zip"

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            create('zip', MavenPublication) {
                groupId "$group"
                artifactId "$artifactWhatever"
                version "$versionWhatever"
                artifact new File("$path")
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'user'
                password 'pwd'
            }
            url "$urlWhataver"
        }
    }
}

publish.dependsOn build
```

There was also a problem with `$path` conversion.